# How to find baseband version through adb?

Tags: android, adb

I am currently trying to get my Wileyfox Swift 2 fixed for a boot-loop caused by installing a custom recovery. All is going well apart from the support agent asking for the baseband version. In the bootloader it does say "BASEBAND VERSION-" but after that nothing. I have also tried running the adb command `adb shell getprop`, however under `[ro.boot.baseband]` all it says is `[msm]`.
Please can someone help me find the baseband version so I can get my phone working quickly.
Thanks.

**Edit:**
I was also wondering what part of the following he needs as the kernel version.

```
Linux version 3.18.24-cyanogen-g1887aec (build-internal02@cyngn) (gcc version 4.
9.x-google 20140827 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Oct 25 15:58:35 PDT
2016
```

Answer (score 3):

For the baseband question: `adb shell getprop gsm.version.baseband` might help you. If not, try `adb shell getprop | grep baseband`.